# Comparing two datasets using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, compare, comparison, logical-operators

Consider the following datasets

```
data_00 <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,6), 
                COLOUR = c("blue","green","yellow","yellow","red","blue","green","green","white","green","blue","yellow","white"))

data_01 <- data.table(ID=c(1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6),
                COLOUR=c("red","blue","green","white","yellow","blue","white","green","blue","white","pink"))

  ID COLOUR
 1:  1   blue
 2:  1  green
 3:  1 yellow
 4:  2 yellow
 5:  2    red
 6:  2   blue
 7:  3  green
 8:  3  green
 9:  3  white
10:  4  green
11:  5   blue
12:  5 yellow
13:  6  white

    ID COLOUR
 1:  1    red
 2:  2   blue
 3:  2  green
 4:  2  white
 5:  3 yellow
 6:  3   blue
 7:  4  white
 8:  4  green
 9:  5   blue
10:  6  white
11:  6   pink
```

with ID representing a person's identification and colour the wall colour of the person's room. I use the data.table package as the real data is very big and thus an efficient package is required. I want to compare the colours stated in b with the colours in a, investigating whether a specific household had this wall colour also in the year before and add a third column to data_01 with the logical values for this question.

I tried with

```
data_01 <- data_01[COLOUR00:=(COLOUR %in% data_00$ID[COLOUR]),by=ID]
but the logical values returned are wrong.
```

The expected output is supposed to be:

```
   ID COLOUR PREV_YEAR
 1:  1    red     FALSE
 2:  2   blue      TRUE
 3:  2  green     FALSE
 4:  2  white     FALSE
 5:  3 yellow     FALSE
 6:  3   blue     FALSE
 7:  4  white     FALSE
 8:  4  green      TRUE
 9:  5   blue      TRUE
10:  6  white      TRUE
11:  6   pink     FALSE
```

I want to have an extra row indicating whether the colour was present in the households home the year before.
Can someone help me tackle this problem?

Comment: What is your expected output? Maybe you need some `*_join`(left_join)? Or use `ifelse` with both IDs and add that to the target dataframe?

Comment: What is the expected output, the answers thus far have 2 different interpretations.

Comment: @NelsonGon,@sindri_baldur I added the expected output to the question.

Comment: @clara_____ why isn't line 8 TRUE?

Comment: @oh you're right it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple approach would be:

```
data_01[, last_year := paste(ID,COLOUR) %chin% data_00[, paste(ID,COLOUR)]]

    ID COLOUR last_year
 1:  1    red     FALSE
 2:  2   blue      TRUE
 3:  2  green     FALSE
 4:  2  white     FALSE
 5:  3 yellow     FALSE
 6:  3   blue     FALSE
 7:  4  white     FALSE
 8:  4  green      TRUE
 9:  5   blue      TRUE
10:  6  white      TRUE
11:  6   pink     FALSE
```

Using joins:

```
data_01[, last_year := FALSE
        ][data_00, on = .(ID,COLOUR), last_year := TRUE]
```

Comment: As above stated - it works! Yet I still struggle with understanding what you did here exactly, would you bother explaining it shortly? I am relatively new to R.

Comment: @clara_____ I think the first solution is more straight-forward we paste the two columns into one and then use `%in%` (`%chin%` is just a fast alternative). The second solution requires some understanding of data.table joins.

Comment: I understand the first solution, I am just trying to understand what you did in the second one :)

Comment: @clara_____ basically you can subset a data.table with another data.table with the matches. Check the result of `data_01[data_00, on = .(ID,COLOUR), nomatch = 0L]`.

Answer (score 2):

OP's approach is to check if a colour in `data_01` is included in the vector of previous year's colours for the same `ID`.

With some modifications to OP's code,

```
data_01[, COLOR00 := COLOUR %in% data_00[.BY == ID, COLOUR], by = ID][]
```

returns the expected result:

> ```
>     ID COLOUR COLOR00
>  1:  1    red   FALSE
>  2:  2   blue    TRUE
>  3:  2  green   FALSE
>  4:  2  white   FALSE
>  5:  3 yellow   FALSE
>  6:  3   blue   FALSE
>  7:  4  white   FALSE
>  8:  4  green    TRUE
>  9:  5   blue    TRUE
> 10:  6  white    TRUE
> 11:  6   pink   FALSE
> ```

Some modifications are due to the differences of the `data.table` syntax to base R `data.frame`.

However, the main trick is to use the special symbol `.BY` to find the rows with matching `ID`. `.BY` is a list containing the items in the  `by =` clause of the actual group. Without `.BY`, we are tempted to write

```
data_01[, COLOR00 := COLOUR %in% data_00[ID == ID, COLOUR], by = ID][]
```

which is ambiguous because `ID` is a column name in both `data_00` and `data_01`.

Anyway, a join as suggested by [sindri_baldur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62674728/3817004) is a cleaner way, IMHO.